# Controller Using ApexPages - Failing Test Class

Tags: unit-test, force.com, controller

I cannot get this controller's test class to pass at all. Please help me understand why I cannot write a test for ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(). I assume the SOQL string should pass the test as I insert a record before it runs.

Controller

```
public class tablestagingController {


public ApexPages.StandardController controller;

public tablestagingController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}


public PageReference saveanddirect() {

    String thfirstname = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('thfirstname');
    String thlastname = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('thlastname');

    controller.save();

    Id recordid = controller.getId();
    String recordname = [SELECT id, Name FROM Reservation_Header__c WHERE id = :recordid].Name;

    PageReference a = new PageReference('http://test.force.com/reservetable/Staging_table_1?Name='+ recordid + '&00N1a000008FU6Z=' + thfirstname + '&00N1a000008FU6U=' + thlastname + '&00NP0000000nbCH=' + recordname);
    a.setRedirect(true);
    return a;


}
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest

public class testclasstablestaging{

public static testMethod void testtablestagingController(){

       Reservation_Header__c a = new Reservation_Header__c (First_Name__c = 'test1', Last_Name__c = 'test2', Phone__c = '703');
       insert a;

       PageReference pageRef1 = new PageReference('/apex/Reservation_Header_KFAK_5');
       apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('thfirstname' , a.First_Name__c);
       apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('thlastname' , a.Last_Name__c);
       Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef1);


       ApexPages.StandardController c = new ApexPages.standardController(a);

       tablestagingController b = new tablestagingController(c);

       System.assert(b != null);

}
}
```

Comment: You need to call `b.saveanddirect()` from your test to get that code executed.

Comment: @KeithC Worked like a charm, can you post it as an answer so I may give you credit?

Comment: Not sure much credit is deserved but adding an accepted answer avoids others looking at a question that is already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `b.saveanddirect()` from your test to get that code executed.